# Java Swing Menu, Popup, Combobox GUI Problem

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, popup, popupmenu

When I click on any popup menu that extends outside the bounds of my frame or dialog, whether it's from a combobox or a menu it doesn't matter, my entire gui goes funky.  It starts replicating panels but only visually.  Everything remains usable just hidden behind a mess.  I've reverted my program to bare bones, 1 frame, 2 buttons, a menu, and 1 dialog.  I shrink the frame so when I click the menu the popup extends down past the bottom of the frame, click the menuitem which brings up a dialog with a couple of buttons.  The first time is fine but after the second time things go very weird.  Everything works perfectly fine if the popup stays within the frame.  Please tell me other people experience this.  Any info would be appreciated.  Google knows nothing about this btw :)

I removed all unnecessary imports, I made sure all gui creation/editing is on EDT, I broke down extended classes and use only base classes, I tried hiding and reusing dialogs, I tried disposing, I found this UIManager.put("PopupMenu.consumeEventOnClose", false) which didn't make much sense but I tried it anyway, nothing worked.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame frame;

    JDialog dialog;

    public Test()
    {
        int width = 336, height = 225;
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        this.frame = new JFrame();
        this.frame.setTitle("Frame");
        this.frame.setLocation((dim.width - width) / 2, (dim.height - height) / 2);
        this.frame.setSize(width, height);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu tools = new JMenu("Tools");
        JMenuItem settings = new JMenuItem("Settings");
        settings.addActionListener(this);
        tools.add(settings);
        menuBar.add(tools);

        this.frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JPanel root = (JPanel)this.frame.getContentPane();
        root.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel flow = new JPanel();
        JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Username: ");
        center.add(label);
        JTextField field = new JTextField("", 10);
        center.add(field);
        flow.add(center);
        root.add(flow);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton cancel = new JButton(" Cancel ");
        cancel.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(cancel);
        root.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        new Test();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        switch(e.getActionCommand())
        {
            case " Cancel ":
            {
                this.frame.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            case "Settings":
            {
                if (this.dialog == null)
                {
                    this.dialog = new JDialog(this.frame, true);
                    this.dialog.setTitle("Settings");
                    this.dialog.setSize(400, 300);
                    this.dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this.frame);
                    this.dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                    JPanel sRoot = (JPanel)this.dialog.getContentPane();
                    sRoot.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
                    JButton close = new JButton(" Close ");
                    close.addActionListener(this);
                    buttonPanel.add(close);

                    sRoot.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                }

                this.dialog.setVisible(true);
                break;
            }
            case " Close ":
            {
                this.dialog.setVisible(false);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just shrink the main frame so the settings menu expands past the bottom of the frame (might have to open and close the settings dialog twice)

[image: screen capture]

Then close the settings dialog, expand the main frame and hover over the button and/or the textfield.

[image: screen capture 2]

It happens to me without fail.

Comment: I copied your code and ran it and did not get the behavior you describe. I make the `JFrame` **very** small and the `JDialog` opens and displays correctly each time I click on _Settings_ menu item and `JFrame` also displays correctly when I close the `JDialog`.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xoo4cy9.png  Make the frame small to allow the menu to extend down past the bottom of the frame.  Click settings and close the dialog.  Do this 1 more time and enlarge the original frame.  Hover over the textbox and let me know if you get this.  https://i.imgur.com/PIrbVt3.png  @Abra

Comment: Still can't reproduce behavior you describe. I'm using JDK 18 on Windows 10.

Comment: @Abra I'm also using JDK 18 on win 10.  I've worked for years with this same code and never noticed it until I ran it on a pc with a high end graphics card (not sure if that's important or not) but I now notice it on my other pc as well.  It happens with every popup that extends over the edge of a frame.  Sometimes on the first go, but usually it's on the second.

Comment: I added -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false on launch and it appears to have corrected the problem @Abra Thank you for your help